# NullPointerException, logical shortcut

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here is a simple code snippet and I cannot figure out why does it throw a `NullPointerException`.

```
  String lastGroup = "";
  menuTevekenysegekGrouped = new ArrayList<MenuElem>();
  for(MenuElem me : menuA) {
    // double checked that me objects are never null
    // double checked that menuA is never null
    if(me.getGroup() != null && !me.getGroup().equals(lastGroup)) { /* NPE!!! */
        lastGroup = me.getGroup();
        MenuElem separ = new MenuElem();
        separ.setCaption(lastGroup);
        separ.setGroupHead(true);
        menuTevekenysegekGrouped.add(separ);
        menuTevekenysegekGrouped.add(me);
    } else {
        menuTevekenysegekGrouped.add(me);
    }
  }
```

In the first iteration the `me.getGroup()` returns `null`. So the first operand of the `&&` is false and second operand should not evaluate according to the JLS, as far as I know. However when I debug the code I get NPE from the marked line. I'd like to know why. (Using JRockit 1.6.0_05 if it matters..)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the stack trace.

Comment: Can you mark the line in which the NPE is thrown (which is seen in the stacktrace).

Comment: To be honest I don't know why but it works now, cannot reproduce the error. I think hot code replace on the Weblogic server would have caused something. Sorry for the bad question. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `me` itself is not, in fact, null?

Comment: yes, I debugged the code even into the `me.getGroup()` method call.

Comment: @jabal, If I were you, I would put extra condition to if clause to check whether me is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

From your code (without the stacktrace I have to guess), the following may be null and be the cause: `menuA` or `me` or `menuTevekenysegekGrouped`. And some of the values returned from the methods/or used in the methods may also be null, but it's hard to know...

Answer (score 0):

If `me` is not null, then the only other object that can be null in the above snippet is `menuTevekenysegekGrouped`.  Add a check before first using it to ensure that it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

The repeated calls to `me.getGroup()` would bug me enough to pull them out into a local variable:

```
  String lastGroup = "";
  for(MenuElem me : menuA) {
    String thisGroup = me.getGroup();
    if(thisGroup != null && !thisGroup.equals(lastGroup)) {
        lastGroup = thisGroup;
        MenuElem separ = new MenuElem();
        separ.setCaption(lastGroup);
        separ.setGroupHead(true);
        menuTevekenysegekGrouped.add(separ);
        menuTevekenysegekGrouped.add(me);
    } else {
        menuTevekenysegekGrouped.add(me);
    }
  }
```

This is only going to fix your problem if in fact `me.getGroup()` returns different values (sometimes null) on multiple calls with the same `me`, but it might make it easier to debug, and certainly makes it easier to read.